# Input into a switch statement to change position of a character.

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a simulation of Travelling sales man problem. So I got random circles spawning and each circle.

I want to make it so I can switch between the circles. Currently the player spawns to the first circle created which is in position (cir[0].x, cir[0].y). However, I'm trying to make an input so you can type in for example 12 and the position of the queen would now be (cir[12].x, cir[12].y). But, this seems to not work.

```
int number;
cin>>number;

if(number<NUMCIRC)
{
    switch(number)
    {
    case number: 
        queenX = cir[number].x;
        queenY= cir[number].y;
        break;

    default: break;

    }
}
```

I was wondering as surely if I input the number and then press enter it should jump to the number. Assuming it's smaller than NUMCIRC, which is the number of circles that I have spawned.

Answer (score 6):

Your `switch` statement is completely superfluous because you're not switching between anything.  The point of an array is you can select a value by its numerical index.  I'm not entirely sure how the `switch` statement will execute with a variable `case`.  Regardless, you can achieve the desired result with the following code.

```
int number; 
cin>>number; 

if(number<NUMCIRC) 
{ 
    queenX = cir[number].x; 
    queenY = cir[number].y; 
}
```

Comment: `case` labels must be Integral Constant Expressions. That's "more constant" than a regular `const`; the compiler has to know the values. But this is indeed the correct solution; `switch` is in no way related to the problem.